# Unable to read Paginator in django template

Tags: python, django

I am setting up a pagination in my Django APP. Following is my view code:

```
class ClaimsView(ListView):
    
    context_object_name = "archives"
    template_name = "myapp/claims.html"
    
    
    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        
        query = self.request.GET.get("q", "")
        
        response = self.get_archives(query)
    
        paginator =Paginator(response, 4)

        pages = paginator.get_pages(4)


        return {'archives': response, 'pages': pages}
```

When I print pages in the viwes file. It give correct result "<page 1 of 1>"

but when I am passing it to the HTML file its not give any results there.
'archives' in above dict has a list as value its working fine but not the 'pages'

This is how I am reading it in HTML file:

```
{{pages}}
```

Answer (score 0):

get queryset method should always return a list or queryset not a dictionary. for pagination...in get of your listview do something like this

```
   def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        response = "your queryset"            
        paginator_obj=Paginator(response,4)
        page_number=self.request.GET.get('page',1)
        students=paginator_obj.get_page(page_number)
        context["page_obj"] = paginator_obj
        if self.request.get_full_path().endswith('/'):
            fullpath = self.request.get_full_path()+'?page='
        else:
            fullpath = self.request.get_full_path()
        context['fullpath'] = fullpath
        context['object_list'] = response
        return render(self.request, self.template_name, context)
```

in your template do something like this

```
    <div class="text-center">
        {% if object_list.has_other_pages  %}
            <ul class="pagination" style="text-align:center; width:100% ;justify-content: center!important;">
                {% if object_list.has_previous %}
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ fullpath }}&page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
                {% else %}
                <li class="page-item" class="disabled"><span class="page-link">&laquo;</span></li>
                {% endif %}
                {% for i in object_list.paginator.page_range %}
                {% if object_list.number == i %}
                    <li class="page-item"class="active"><span  class="page-link">{{ i }} <span  class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ fullpath }}&page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% if object_list.has_next %}
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ fullpath }}&page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
                {% else %}
                <li  class="page-item" class="disabled"><span class="page-link">&raquo;</span></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

Comment: still not working!

Comment: check my updated answer please